# Unable to click on element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

I'm working on a program that will help me select the 2nd option in the dropdown menu on https://www.pcfinancial.ca/ located in the upper-right corner of the window. Here's my code so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get('https://www.pcfinancial.ca/');
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkSignInOp"]').click() #click on dropdown menu - working
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click() #select "pc mastercard" - not working
```

What's weird is I can access the dropdown menu using the first `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...)` line but I get the following error when selecting the 2nd option.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imad\Documents\Programming\Python\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click() #open up dropdown menu works
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic case of a *timing issue*. After you open the dropdown, wait for the menu link to be clickable with [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://www.pcfinancial.ca/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkSignInOp"]').click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#PCM a"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no idea a wait time is involved after the webpage has actually loaded. As for WebDriverWait, do you know what unit the 10 is in? Just asking out of curiosity so I know what's "too long" next time

Comment: @ImadKalboneh no problem, glad it worked for you. 10 is in "seconds", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `WebSite` the **`WebElement`** by the linkText **`PC MasterCard`** is within an **`<a>`** tag, so we will construct a unique `xpath` as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.pcfinancial.ca/');
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkSignInOp"]').click() #click on dropdown menu - working
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#PCM' and @rel='/re_register/index.html']").click() #click on "PC MasterCard" - now working
print("Clicked on PC MasterCard")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that actually is one of the things I tried. Sadly, I got the same error. I got the answer from the previous person though.